# Copy selected text to Clipboard in MSWord, OOWriter, etc

Tags: winapi, clipboard

I have code on Delphi (but this not principal)

```
 hWindow := GetForegroundWindow;
 EditHandle := GetTopWindow(hWindow);
 SendMessage(EditHandle, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
 SClipboard := Clipboard.AsText;
```

If this code worked for Notepad - all very good. If another, not simple editor, selected text not copyed to clipboard.
How I can to execute copy text to clipboard? 
I suspect that SendMessage does not work.

Comment: but not any window handle `WM_COPY`. `GetTopWindow(hWindow);` can simply not be edit or combobox

Comment: Also, try using `WM_GETTEXT` instead of `WM_COPY`, then you don't need to mess around with the clipboard at all, which really should be reserved for the user's use only.

Comment: The code in question operates on native windows. Few applications these days use native windows. A reliable solution is based on [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32), a system that's independent of the underlying windowing system.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ,unfortunately,[WM_GETTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettext): *For an edit control, the text to be copied is the content of the edit control. For a combo box, the text is the content of the edit control (or static-text) portion of the combo box. For a button, the text is the button name. **For other windows, the text is the window title.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Not all the top windows are the edit control. So, `EditHandle` is unpredictable.

Then, [`WM_COPY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copy) is only supported in edit control or combo box. The same goes for [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettext), They do not support all windows. 
You are not able to change its message processing mechanism unless you're the owner of Windows.

However, there is a workaround--Simulate "Ctrl + C" keyboard input to target window.

```
//SetForegroundWindow(hWindow); Since hWindow is already a Foreground Window
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), 0, 0);    // Ctrl down
keybd_event(ord('C'), MapVirtualKey(ord('C'), 0), 0, 0);        // C down
keybd_event(ord('C'), MapVirtualKey(ord('C'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);     // C up
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Ctrl up
```

EDIT:

Since the `keybd_event` has been superseded by `SendInput`, Here is a C++ sample for using `SendInput`:

```
INPUT input[4] = {0};
input[0].type = input[1].type = input[2].type = input[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[0].ki.wVk = input[3].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
input[0].ki.wScan = input[3].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
input[1].ki.wVk = input[2].ki.wVk = 'C';
input[1].ki.wScan = input[2].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey('C', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
input[2].ki.dwFlags = input[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // there is no KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN
SendInput(4, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: `keybd_event()` had been deprecated for a long time, use `SendInput()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for point out, a reminder was added in my edit.

Comment: Thanks you! Works.